# Acessing Web Service in SSL Using HttpWebRequest

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have doubt in Windows 7 Phone Application Development.

I need to acess the web service using HttpWebRequest in SSL How can I configure HttpWebRequest as for SSL and allow if Certificate is InValid..

For Example:

I need to Acess API "www.example.com?value=stringVale" and I will get a response as XML and I need to Process It.

when I Give a URI as "https://www.example.com/mainPage.php?Value=stringVale" I get an Breaking Issue.

so How can I access webservice using HttpRequest with SSL Layer.. with InValid Certificate?

Thanks 
Dinesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a certificate issued by an authority that is recognised by the platform.

This is the latest list I've seen (posted by Shaun Taulbee) in this thread.

[push notifications from authenticated services](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/62133.aspx)

You can get a 30 day trial cert that's handy for testing from GeoTrust.